# Suggestions for reducing allocations (and work) in this Haskell function

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, allocation

I have the following function in my (much larger) Haskell code (with some supporting code to make it clear what's what):

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Data.Ord
import Data.Monoid

data Atom = Neg { index :: Int }
          | Pos { index :: Int }
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read) 

newtype Clause = Clause { atoms :: S.Set Atom }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Ord Clause where
  compare = comparing (Down . S.size . atoms) <> comparing atoms

newtype Form = Form { clauses :: S.Set Clause }
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

type Interpretation = M.IntMap Bool

-- the function of interest
interpret :: Interpretation -> Form -> Maybe Bool
interpret interp = evalForm
  where evalAtom x@(Pos _) = M.lookup (index x) interp
        evalAtom x@(Neg _) = not <$> M.lookup (index x) interp
        evalClause (Clause x)
          | S.member (Just False) evaluated = Just False
          | evaluated == S.singleton (Just True) = Just True
          | otherwise = Nothing
          where evaluated = S.map evalAtom x
        evalForm (Form x)
          | S.member (Just True) evaluated = Just True
          | evaluated == S.singleton (Just False) = Just False
          | otherwise = Nothing
          where evaluated = S.map evalClause x
```

Having profiled my Haskell program, I've found that this `interpret` function's allocations comprise nearly 40% of all allocations in my program (as well as about 40% of the CPU work).

Is there any way I can reduce either the amount of work `interpret` does, or the amount it allocates? This could potentially win me big performance gains (which I could really need, as I need to run this code many times, for experiments).

Comment: Since you don't give much context, I can't really come up with any out-of-box ideas. But you might consider whether it would be better to represent a `Clause` as two `IntSet`s, one for the `Neg` values and one for the `Pos` values. You should also note that a `Set` of sets is generally likely to be slow, but that's more a result of comparison costs than allocation.

Comment: @dfeuer My main motivation for using sets for both ``Clause``s and ``Form``s is that I want them to have unique membership. Is there an alternative structure I can use which won't have the problem you're describing regarding sets of sets being slow?

Comment: Unique membership? I'm not sure what you mean. If an element should appear as `Neg` or `Pos` but not both, you don't accomplish that. To get that, you should use `data Sign = Neg | Pos`, and then `IntMap Sign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would experiment with `S.foldr`.

From your code, it looks as if these are AND-clauses, so I will assume an empty clause is false.

```
evalClause (Clause x) = S.foldr f (Just False) $ S.map evalAtom x
     where f b@(Just False) _              = b
           f (Just True)    y              = y
           f Nothing        y@(Just False) = y
           f Nothing        y              = Nothing
```

and the analogous for `evalForm`.

It might also be beneficial to use lists rather than sets. Sets, as implemented, are strict, and (I think) will not trigger some optimizations like fusion/deforestation/etc. Lists are lazily produced, and should behave better in this sort of code.

```
evalClause (Clause x) = foldr f (Just False) . map evalAtom $ S.toList x
     ...
```

Answer (score 2):

An observation:

A `Maybe Bool` can only have three possible values - `Nothing`, `Just False` and `Just True`.

`evaluated` in both `evalClause` and `evalForm` has type `Set (Maybe Bool)` which can be represented with three bits which fits in a Int.

I would define:

```
data MaybeBool = Nuthin | JustFalse | JustTrue
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded, Show, Read)
```

and change the signature of `intepret` return a `MaybeBool`

Then define `evaluated` as a bitset like this:

```
import Data.Bits

evaluated = foldl' combine 0 (map evalAtom (S.toList x))
  where combine s a = s .|. (1 `shiftLeft` fromEnum a)
```

`evaluated` will be a Int between 0 and 7 with bit 0 set if `Nutin` is in the set, bit 1 set if `JustFalse` is in the set and bit 2 set if `JustTrue` is in the set. This will eliminate allocation of Sets from your computation.